# Is there a C++ standard-compliant way to obtain a reference to a known base class of a coroutine promise?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, c++-coroutine

In a couple of places in my C++ coroutine library I need to walk a chain of suspended coroutines that are waiting on each other.

For example, assume that `Foo0` calls `Foo1`, which calls `Foo2`, which… calls `FooN`, each `co_await`s the result of the next, and `FooN` is currently suspended. Their promise types store the handle of the awaiter to resume when they're done, so they form a singly-linked list from `FooN` to `Foo0`. I want to be able to iterate over the list, e.g. to clean up after cancellation or to give a nice async stack trace for profiling.

If all of the coroutines have the same promise type, this is easy as long as I have a handle for the last coroutine frame. I can implement it something like this:

```cpp
void WalkCoroutineChain(std::coroutine_handle<Promise> h) {
  while (h) {
    // ... do something with h ...
    Visit(h);
    
    // Move on to the caller of h's coroutine.
    h = h.promise().awaiter;
  }
}
```

The problem is that in reality they don't all have the same promise type. They share a common promise type *template*, and even a single common base class for the promise type, but the promise type itself differs because it is templated on the type of result they return.

---

My question is: given a reference to a promise, is there any legal way to store it as something type-erased like `void*` or `std::coroutine_handle<>` while retaining the ability to do both of the following operations via that type-erased value?

1. Resume or destroy its coroutine.
2. Obtain a reference to its known base class. (If it helps, I can guarantee there is no multiple inheritance.)

This would allow me to solve my problem because I could put the `awaiter` member into a common untemplated base class that all of the promises inherit from, and walk a list of those.

I'm pretty sure in practice it would probably work out to just do this:

```cpp
std::coroutine_handle<> type_erased = GetHandleSomehow();
auto base = std::coroutine_handle<PromiseBase>::from_address(type_erased.address());
```

But this is probably undefined behavior:

- In the C++20 draft [[coroutine.handle.export.import]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/coroutine.handle.export.import) lists as a precondition for `std::coroutine_handle<Promise>::from_address` "`addr` was obtained via a prior call to `address`", without saying anything about the type of the callee of `address`.
- In the [latest draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/coroutine.handle.export.import) it says specifically "`addr` was obtained via a prior call to `address` on an object of type *cv* `coroutine_­handle<Promise>`", which wouldn't be true if `Promise` is actually a base class for the real promise type.

Comment: "*I want to be able to iterate over the list, e.g. to clean up after cancellation or to give a nice async stack trace for profiling.*" Can't you just throw an exception? Like, resume the coroutine in such a way as it emits an exception. And then each coroutine, and its promise, passes that exception along through the various futures.

Comment: That might work (I haven't thought it through), except this is in an environment with exceptions disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following is likely to work in practice, at least in the simple case where there is no multiple inheritance or virtual functions (i.e. when the base class and the promise class are [pointer-interconvertible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pointer_interconvertible_base_of)):

```cpp
// Assume the promise inherits from a base class.
struct PromiseBase {
  // The handle to resume when done, also used for walking the linked list as
  // described in the question.
  std::coroutine_handle<PromiseBase> awaiter;
};

template <typename Result>
struct Promise : PromiseBase {
  std::coroutine_handle<PromiseBase> get_base_handle() {
    std::coroutine_handle<PromiseBase>::from_promise(*this);
  }
};
```

`PromiseBase::awaiter` can be used as the link to walk in a `WalkCoroutineChain` function, rather than `std::coroutine_handle<Promise<T>>`, since `T` may vary across the chain of coroutines.

---

I read both the [C++20 draft](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/coroutine.handle#con-2) and the [latest draft](https://eel.is/c++draft/coroutine.handle#con-2) of the standard as saying the implementation of `get_base_handle` is legal: the precondition for `std::coroutine_handle<PromiseBase>::from_promise` is only that the input reference is "a reference to a promise object of a coroutine". That is surely true of `*this` in that context, and presumably still true even when converted to a reference to `PromiseBase`.

I say this is "likely to work in practice" because I'm not 100% confident in the intent of the standard. Perhaps this is meant to be forbidden? But if so, it is certainly not clear. In the absence of clear wording it's also worth considering implementability, and I see no reason that this wouldn't work correctly given how coroutine handles are implemented in clang/libc++ today (a `void*` pointer to the coroutine frame with the promise at a known offset); this seems true at least in the absence of multiple inheritance and virtual functions.

If the intent of the standard is to say this is not legal, then I think the wording could be improved. I've filed an [issue](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/6039) on the standard's GitHub repo to ask for clarification.

Comment: "*"a reference to a promise object of a coroutine". That is surely true of *this in that context*" Is it, though? `*this` is a reference to the promise, but that is of type `Promise`. Once it becomes a reference to the base class, does that still count as a "reference to a promise object?" That is, is a reference to a base class also a reference to the dynamic object? [There is evidence that it is not](https://lists.isocpp.org/std-discussion/2022/12/1961.php)

Comment: Yeah, like I said I’m not 100% sure about the intent here, although it seems pretty clear to me that this _could_ be defined to work if they are pointer interconvertible, given the way that a coroutine handle is actually implemented. Hence the GitHub issue. I hadn’t found that thread before; thanks for the link.

Comment: Oh huh I didn’t notice the timestamp of the thread; maybe it was started because of my issue. If not, fun coincidence in timing in any case.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get a promise *of any kind* from a `std::coroutine_handle<>`. That is basically the entire point of that specialization: to interact with a coroutine without caring what type of promise it contains.

> But this is probably undefined behavior:

That [LWG issue 3460](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3460). It specifically makes it clear that `coroutine_handle<T>::from_address` requires that the address was obtained specifically from an instance of `coroutine_handle<T>`. This was applied as a defect of C++20, so it's part of the standard.

Comment: I don't think it's true that there's no way to get a promise from the type-erased version. You can ask for its address and feed that to `from_address` on the non-type erased version. Perhaps it's UB today, but this is equivalent to my overall question: is there any non-UB way to obtain a "partially type erased" reference to a promise, through a base class or in any other manner, so that I can legally access a variable that I know is at a particular offset within the promise. I see that LWG 3460 added the wording I quoted, but the requirements it added seem to be stronger than necessary.

Comment: @jacobsa: "*You can ask for its address and feed that to from_address on the non-type erased version.*" No, you can't. LWG3460 makes it very clear that `coroutine_handle<T>::from_address` *only* works if the pointer was obtained from a non-type-erased handle. You cannot undo type erasure.

Comment: I read [coroutine.handle.export.import](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/support.coroutine#coroutine.handle.export.import) as guaranteeing that the address will round trip, so it should be possible to do so without UB as long as the type-erased version was itself created from the address returned by `coroutine_handle<T>::address`. But regardless that is not the point of my question—the point is to ask how I can legally walk a linked list with erasure of the templated class but not the base class.

Comment: @jacobsa: "*I read [[coroutine.handle.export.import]](timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/…) as*" The defect report in question is written *against* that version. It supersedes that version. It's a bug fix, and you're looking at the bugged version.

Comment: Yes sorry, I linked the wrong version. The [latest draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/coroutine.handle.export.import) is even more clear that the address should round trip and what I describe is legal. But again **that is not the point of my question.**

Comment: @jacobsa: "*But regardless that is not the point of my question*" Um, yes it is. You didn't ask about a way to solve that problem. You asked about a way to make your desired solution to that problem work. It's even the very title of your question. If you want any solution to that problem, you should ask a new question specifically about that, without any notion of a particular solution.

Comment: @jacobsa: "*The latest draft is even more clear that the address should round trip and what I describe is legal.*" Maybe you should read that again. In your example, `type_erased` is *not* a `coroutine_handle<Promise>`; it's a `coroutine_handle<>` The address you pass to `coroutine_handle<Promise>::from_address` is therefore ***not*** "obtained via a prior call to `address` on an object of type cv `coroutine_­handle<Promise>`." Violating the precondition of a function yields UB.

Comment: I'll quote directly from my question: "is there any legal way to obtain a reference to a promise as a base class from a type-erased `std::coroutine_handle<>`". Your answer doesn't mention base classes at all; it says that round-tripping through the type-erased version is illegal in general. If that were true then this would be a partial answer to my question, but it is not as far as I can tell. It seems to be legal to feed the output of `handle<Promise>::address` to `handle<>::from_address`, and then feed `handle<>::address` to `handle<Promise>::from_address` according to the latest draft.

Comment: @jacobsa: Please read the text of the draft. It specifically says ***not that***.

Comment: Very helpful response, thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250649/discussion-between-nicol-bolas-and-jacobsa).